# OpenSL ES RegisterCallback causes crash

Tags: crash, opensl

I have to use OpenSL for my project (tried Soundpool but it's not good at all). However, after playing the sound multiple times (around 35 continuous times), the app is shutdown (I guess maybe because of overflow).

I tried to free the buffer/memory to solve the problem (and for god sake, I don't know how to do by using this OpenSL). So I decided to try to free when the file was finished playing. OpenSL ES provide us the `RegisterCallback` function which might help. New problem occurred, in my case (using URI file), `RegisterCallback` caused my app crash again. It's stuck.

Here is my code. Please help. It crashed right after `//register callback for uri`.

```
static short fdBuffer[SAWTOOTH_FRAMES];

// create URI audio player
    jboolean Java_jp_mobigame_ayakashi_CardGameActivity_createUriAudioPlayer(JNIEnv* env, jclass clazz,
            jstring uri)
    {
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "LOG_TAG", "\n createUri \n");
        SLresult result;

        // convert Java string to UTF-8
        const jbyte *utf8 = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, uri, NULL);
        assert(NULL != utf8);

        // configure audio source
        // (requires the INTERNET permission depending on the uri parameter)
        SLDataLocator_URI loc_uri = {SL_DATALOCATOR_URI, (SLchar *) utf8};
        SLDataFormat_MIME format_mime = {SL_DATAFORMAT_MIME, NULL, SL_CONTAINERTYPE_UNSPECIFIED};
        SLDataSource audioSrc = {&loc_uri, &format_mime};

        // configure audio sink
        SLDataLocator_OutputMix loc_outmix = {SL_DATALOCATOR_OUTPUTMIX, outputMixObject};
        SLDataSink audioSnk = {&loc_outmix, NULL};

        // create audio player
        const SLInterfaceID ids[3] = {SL_IID_SEEK, SL_IID_MUTESOLO /*SL_IID_BUFFERQUEUE*/, SL_IID_VOLUME};
        const SLboolean req[3] = {SL_BOOLEAN_TRUE, SL_BOOLEAN_TRUE, SL_BOOLEAN_TRUE};
        result = (*engineEngine)->CreateAudioPlayer(engineEngine, &uriPlayerObject, &audioSrc,
                &audioSnk, 3, ids, req);
        // note that an invalid URI is not detected here, but during prepare/prefetch on Android,
        // or possibly during Realize on other platforms
        assert(SL_RESULT_SUCCESS == result);

        // release the Java string and UTF-8
        (*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, uri, utf8);

        // realize the player
        result = (*uriPlayerObject)->Realize(uriPlayerObject, SL_BOOLEAN_FALSE);
        // this will always succeed on Android, but we check result for portability to other platforms
        if (SL_RESULT_SUCCESS != result) {
            (*uriPlayerObject)->Destroy(uriPlayerObject);
            uriPlayerObject = NULL;
            return JNI_FALSE;
        }

        // get the play interface
        result = (*uriPlayerObject)->GetInterface(uriPlayerObject, SL_IID_PLAY, &uriPlayerPlay);
        assert(SL_RESULT_SUCCESS == result);

        // get the seek interface
        result = (*uriPlayerObject)->GetInterface(uriPlayerObject, SL_IID_SEEK, &uriPlayerSeek);
        assert(SL_RESULT_SUCCESS == result);


        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "LOG_TAG", "\n createUri 1\n");
        //get the buffer queue interface
        result = (*uriPlayerObject)->GetInterface(uriPlayerObject, SL_IID_ANDROIDSIMPLEBUFFERQUEUE, &uriPlayerBufferQueue);
        assert(SL_RESULT_SUCCESS == result);
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "LOG_TAG", "\n createUri 2\n");


        //register callback for uri
        result = (*uriPlayerBufferQueue)->RegisterCallback(uriPlayerBufferQueue, bqUriPlayerCallback, NULL);
        assert(SL_RESULT_SUCCESS == result);
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "LOG_TAG", "\n createUri 4\n");

        //Enqueue
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "LOG_TAG", "\n createUri 3\n");
        result = (*uriPlayerBufferQueue)->Enqueue(uriPlayerBufferQueue, fdBuffer, sizeof(fdBuffer));


        // get the mute/solo interface
        result = (*uriPlayerObject)->GetInterface(uriPlayerObject, SL_IID_MUTESOLO, &uriPlayerMuteSolo);
        assert(SL_RESULT_SUCCESS == result);

        // get the volume interface
        result = (*uriPlayerObject)->GetInterface(uriPlayerObject, SL_IID_VOLUME, &uriPlayerVolume);
        assert(SL_RESULT_SUCCESS == result);

        return JNI_TRUE;

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to get a buffer queue interface, even though you are specifying a uri source.  You also appear to be enqueing data.  If you are just trying to play audio from a uri, you shouldn't need to do this.  If you are trying to output to a buffer instead of the speakers, then this may be valid.  I'm no OpenSL expert by any means, so there could be a reason for this.  However, if there isn't a reason for that, try registering the callback on the player object instead.

```
(*uriPlayerPlay)->RegisterCallback(uriPlayerPlay, bqUriPlayerCallback, NULL);
```

As a side note, you will probably want to set the callback event mask.  There are several options, but I believe the one you are looking for is:

```
(*uriPlayerPlay)->SetCallbackEventsMask(uriPlayerPlay, SL_PLAYEVENT_HEADATEND)
```

Please note that there might be issues with this. See https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-ndk/7YaqlKlDMO4.

If this doesn't help, it might be helpful to see your definition of the callback function.  I believe it should look something like:

```
static void bqUriPlayerCallback (SLPlayItf caller, void *pContext, SLuint32 playevent)
```